# How to Manage transactions in jax-rs without using spring's @Transactional beans

Tags: java, rest, transactions, jersey, jax-rs

I am developing a RESTful Web Service using Jersey(JAX-RS). I need transaction support in my application. I searched on the web for this and at most of places , I am getting answers(suggestions) of using Spring's transaction support, but I am not using Spring at all and do not want to use Spring's transaction support(applying @Transactional annotation). Is there any other way to get transaction support in Jersey without using Spring's transaction support. And If there is not any transaction support in Jersey then how can I implement this on my own.
Thanks in advance.

Below is the exact scenario:
In my architecture, I am having 3 layers, 1. Application layer(API layer), 2.service layer and 3.database service layer. Now, if a service consumes 2 or more database services, then it must commit only if **all** the database services get executed successfully, otherwise it must rollback. So, basically I want the transaction support in service layer.

Comment: Your question is overly broad. From where do you want to get transaction support? You imply you are using Jersey in a Spring environment.

Comment: @Steve11235 I am not using Spring at all and do not want to use Spring's Transactional support.

Comment: Consider using a JTA Transaction Manager ( Atomikos ,Bitronix ) or an full JavaEE Application Server

Comment: Well, that rules out @Transactional! What transaction support do you want to use? Are you in a JEE container? What support does it provide?

Comment: @Steve11235, I want transactional support for multiple services.
Scenario: I am having service layer and database layer separately, and in service layer if I call 2 or more methods in database layer then it must commit only if all the method calls are executed successfully otherwise it must rollback. So I want the transaction support in service layer.

Answer (score 0):

You need transaction management to accomplish that. JEE containers and Spring provide that. You can also use stand-alone frameworks, like Atomikos. Finally, if all your transactional work is handled by a single JDBC connection, you can use commit/rollback. The starting point is to look at the environment you are using to support your services and database access and then to decide how you want to handle  transactions.